# Shadow line above context menu when using HoloEverywhere

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, contextmenu, android-holo-everywhere

I am using HoloEverywhere (and ActionBarSherlock) to create a consistent user interface on all devices.

Unfortunately, my app shows a strange thin shadow line above the context menus when running on an ICS (4.0.4) device:

[image: Shadow line on ICS device]

Running the same app on a Froyo (2.2) device shows a perfect context menu without the shadow line:

[image: No shadow line on Froyo device]

Any idea how to correct this?